Find a solution of a functional inequality
Suppose that $K=1/\sqrt{2}$. Find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is not additive and
$$|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)|\le K|f(x+y)+f(x-y)-2f(x)|$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.
It follows from $K=1/\sqrt{2}$ that every solution must satisfy $f(2x)=2f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Are you sure this even has a solution?

With little tricks you can check that $f$ is at least $\mathbb Q$-multiplicative

@TahirImanov you made a computation mistake

Partial answer only
As you probably did with $y = 0$ you get:
$$|f(0)| \le 0$$
Thus $f(0) = 0$. Then by setting $x= y$
$$|f(2x)-2f(x)| \le \sqrt\frac{1}{2} |f(2x)-2f(x)|$$
thus $f(2x) = 2f(x)$.
Now let us set $y = -x$, we get
$$|f(x) + f(-x)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |f(2x) - 2f(x)| = 0$$
Thus $f(-x) = -f(x)$.
Now set $y = 3x$, you get
$$|3f(x)-f(3x)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |f(4x) + f(-2x) -2f(x)| = 0$$
Thus $f(3x) = 3 f(x)$.
By induction, let us suppose that for the $n-1$ first prime numbers we have $f(p_ix) = p_if(x)$. And we take $p_n$ the $n$-th prime number and set $y = p_n x$.
A first observation is that $p_n \nmid p_n-1,p_n+1$ thus $p_n - 1 = \prod_{k<n} p_k^{\alpha_k}$ and $p_n + 1 =\prod_{k<n} p_k^{\beta_k}$.
This means that $\forall x,$ $f((p_n-1)x) = (p_n-1)f(x)$ and $f(p_n+1)x) = (p_n+1) f(x)$, thus we get
$$|f((p_n + 1) x) - f(x) - f(p_n x)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |f((p_n + 1) x) + f((p_n - 1) x) - 2f(x)|$$
so
$$|(p_n + 1 -1)f(x) - f(p_n x)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |(p_n + 1 +1-p_n -2) f(x)| = 0$$
Which means $f(p_n x) = p_n f(x)$.
Thus $\forall n \in \mathbb Z, f(nx) = nf(x)$ which means $\forall q \in \mathbb Q, \, f(qx) = qf(x)$.
Now showing some smoothness at one point different from zero would be very useful.

From now on these are only ideas
Now set $x+y = 2z$. You get
$$|f(2z)-f(z+y) -f(z-y)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |f(x+y) + f(x-y) -2f(x)|$$
Which means for $y \neq 0$
$$ \left| \frac{f(z+y) -f(z) - (f(z)-f(z-y))}{y^2} \right| \le
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  \left| \frac{f(x+y) -f(x) - (f(x)-f(x-y))}{y^2} \right|$$
We define $g(x,y) = \frac{f(x+y) -f(x) - (f(x)-f(x-y))}{y^2}$ for $y \neq 0$. Note that if $\lim_{y\to 0}g(x,y) = l$ exists, $f$ is two times derivable at $x$ and $f''(x) = l$. It also verifies
$|g((x+y)/2,y) \le |g(x,y)|/\sqrt 2$.
